# Does the URI scheme "View Source" cause the browser to load the content of the page?

Tags: url, browser, view-source

Would the URI Scheme "View source" cause the content of a page to be loaded by the browser?

For example, typing in the address bar of Chrome `view-source:https://www.google.com` would show you the source code for google.com where as typing in `https://www.google.com` would show you the page we all know.

So my question is related to suspected phishing/malware sites. If I think a particular URL is malicious but want to verify by checking the source code, **would going to `view-source:https://www.malicioussite.com` cause my browser to load the content of that page or not?**

I normally use sites like WebSniffer.cc to check but it would be useful if this allowed the same.

Comment: That looks like something Chrome-specific, not a standard URI scheme.  Whether or not Chrome requests other page resources I guess you could test easily enough.  But if you want to examine just the response from that URL itself with no additional page resources then you probably don't want to load anything in a *web browser*, but rather make a standalone HTTP request to that URL and examine the response.  Browser plugins like Postman can help with that, or any application code that you might write to make HTTP requests.

Comment: I found the following document from IETF describing it. However it did state it was a draft so not sure if they adopted it. "https://tools.ietf.org/html/draft-yevstifeyev-view-source-uri-00"